# This is How Google Bot Fetched My Site

Tags: fetch, bots

This is how a Google bot views my site -

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /LageX/
```

What does it mean? Is it good or bad? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's bad**.

The above indicates that the content of your site is temporarily available at another location. Unless you have a good reason to set up a temporary (302) redirect, you should either move your content to where it is expected or set up a permanent (301) redirect.

The `Location:` header which is expected to hold the URI where the content is available is itself invalid, because its value is expected to be an absolute URI — something like `http://domain.com/LageX/`.

Comment: could it be because once a user comes to my site example.com. then if he clicks on the logo, he goes to example.com/index.php. What could the reasons be? Thanks so much for your help. best answer.

Comment: It shouldn't depend on what users do. All that matters is what your web server responds when it receives an HTTP request for a certain page. See your web server configuration (or your web site) for changing these things.